# Error querying database

Tags: c#, sql

My code :

```
var db = Database.Open("dbase");
var result = db.Query("SELECT event_id, description, title, event_start, event_end 
                       FROM event 
                       WHERE event_start >= "+ start + " AND event_end <= "+ @end);

foreach(var record in result)
{
   CalendarEvent cevent = new CalendarEvent();
   cevent.id = result.event_id; //error is thrown here
}
```

Error message :

> CS1061: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not
>   contain a definition for 'event_id' and no extension method 'event_id'
>   accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

In my code I have :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using WebMatrix.Data;
```

What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to start with, you probably meant `record.event_id` instead of `result.event_id`. Your code would be clearer if you changed `result` to `results`, given that it's the *sequence* of results.

However, that's just going to move the problem on one stage. [`Database.Query`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.data.database.query%28v=vs.99%29.aspx) returns an `IEnumerable<object>`, so the type of `record` is going to be `object`... and `object` doesn't have a member called `event_id` either.

The documentation for `Database.Query` is pretty vague - it's possible that it's returning dynamic objects though. Try this:

```
foreach (dynamic record in result)
{
        CalendarEvent cevent = new CalendarEvent();
        cevent.id = record.event_id;
}
```

EDIT: If `record.event_id` is working even *without* converting to `dynamic`, then it's possible that the *effective* result type is `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and MSDN is just not being terribly helpful.

However, there's still a problem in your code: it's a bad idea to include your parameter values directly in your SQL like that:

- Mixing code and data is a bad idea in terms of code cleanliness
- You need to make sure that dates, numbers etc are in the right format
- It opens you up to SQL injection attacks

Instead, you should use a *parameterized query* like this:

```
var result = db.Query(
     "SELECT event_id, description, title, event_start, event_end FROM event " +
     "where event_start >= ? AND event_end <= ?",
     start, end);
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't

```
cevent.id = result.event_id; //error is thrown here
```

be

```
cevent.id = record.event_id;
```

if anything?

Comment: This appears to have fixed my problem! Why is record used here, that seems a little counter intuitive?

Comment: @SimonKiely: `results` indicates the *whole sequence* of results. `record` is *the individual record that you're looking at in the loop at the moment*.

Comment: Why? Result is an IEnumerable of what ever you try to find. The objects (record) may or may not have all the properties you try to query for (too little contxt to tell), but result will definetly never have any of the properties mentioned in the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
cevent.id = result.event_id; //error is thrown here
```

should be:

```
cevent.id = record.event_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to have

`cevent.id = record.event_id;`